# Vim syntax Highlighting

Tags: vim, color-scheme, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have installed vim in Debian 6. I am trying to change color scheme and enable syntax highlighting. But it's not working. I added `set background=dark` in `.vimrc` file. But white background is displaying. I wonder what went wrong?

Here is my `.vimrc` file: http://pastebin.com/8k2gpWDh

I installed [robokai](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3478) colorscheme which has dark background. But the background looks white instead dark. Other colors of colorscheme working.

Comment: Have you install the full `vim`? By default, Debian installs only `vim-tiny` that does not support syntax coloring.

Comment: Thanks.Added syntax on.I added set background=dark in vimrc file.But background is still white.

Comment: @Didier Trosset :Installed `vim-common` and `vim-runtime` as well

Answer (score 15):

Make sure you have

```
syntax on
```

And then call

```
color[scheme] {name}
```

To set your desired colorscheme. These contain the `set background=dark` you
refered, so it should be a matter of choosing the right one. Vim comes with some
color schemes, but you may want to install new ones.

[This page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_the_color_scheme) and [this one](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switch_color_schemes) provide tips on color schemes, and [there is a
test page](http://code.google.com/p/vimcolorschemetest/) very helpful when choosing colorschemes.

Answer (score 2):

robokai seem to be written for a 16 color terminal, a linux console probably, but i am guessing here. To make it work if you are using a terminal emulator (like xterm, gnome-terminal, konsole, etc) you may use `set t_Co=16` before loading the color scheme or force your terminal type to linux when running vim (`TERM=linux vim ...`), and manually set a dark background in your terminal emulator,

Also run `dpkg --get-selections | grep vim`. For vim to work in full you need to see one of: vim-gnome, vim-gtk, vim-lesstiff or vim-nox (for systems without a graphical desktop).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a terminal emulator like konsole or gnome-terminal, install vim-gtk or vim-gnome, get [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390), and add `set t_Co=256` to your .vimrc. This will give you support for *any* color scheme, in the terminal, even those which supposedly only support gvim.

Comment: Thanks!  xfce-terminal suddenly changed its compat from xterm to xterm-256color and that messed up my colorscheme. I added set t_Co=8 to the file to restore the previous interpretation of color codes.