# R syntax highlighting in Terminal

Tags: r, terminal

Can we get syntax highlighting for R in the Terminal?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've finally found a library that meets my needs.
Now I'm much happier with my coding environment.

> [colorout](https://github.com/jalvesaq/colorout) is an R package that colorizes R output when running in a terminal emulator.The package cannot be on CRAN because it changes code already loaded by R and this is prohibited by the CRAN Repository Policy. The package replaces the functions that output results and messages to R Console, and this is necessary because we cannot colorize the output without replacing these functions. To install it, do the following in R:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("jalvesaq/colorout")
library("colorout")
# do something
```

Comment: How do we get library("colorout") to run each time we open an R session?

Comment: @Nikos add it to your `.Rprofile` ;-)
See https://www.r-bloggers.com/fun-with-rprofile-and-customizing-r-startup/

Answer (score 5):

Use something like [ess](http://ess.r-project.org/) on emacs or [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com) for syntax highlighting for R instead of expecting it to work in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Another option now would be to use [radian](https://github.com/randy3k/radian) instead of the default R prompt.

Answer (score 0):

As hd1 indicated, this is not an R question.  You're asking the OSX `Terminal.app` to do something it's not capable of.  A quick look around Google (happy Zamboni birthday!) shows [Vim syntax Highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309083/vim-syntax-highlighting)  for highlighting within `vim` , or https://superuser.com/questions/72057/terminal-emulator-with-custom-color-palette , but dunno if these will run under Darwin.

EDIT:  I can't stay away from the search :-) .  So check out these threads:  https://superuser.com/questions/400360/syntax-highlighting-in-terminal-mac-os-x  , http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=412609 , and a recommendation to install `zsh` , https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12161/os-x-terminal-must-have-utilities

Comment: Mac OS X comes with `zsh` out of the box.

Comment: @hd1  Oops-- I quoted the wrong thing. The special goody is "oh-my-zsh" or some such enhancement app.

Comment: @hd1  yup, that's the one.