# What does it mean when the variable name T is highlighted?

Tags: r, syntax-highlighting

I understand that R highlights specific text depending on its function, but what does it mean when the variable you are assigning is highlighted? And can it cause any problems? For example, `T` is highlighted automatically in:

[image: T highlighted]

Comment: `T` is a logical value that means `TRUE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better **not** to use `T` in R as a variable. The reason `T` is highlighted is that it is used as an abbreviation for `TRUE`. If you use `T` as a variable, you can no longer use it as `TRUE` and its definition will be overwritten.

Comment: No, `t` transposes a matrix. `T` is a variable name which by default is assigned to `TRUE` but can be overwritten. Similarly `F` is a synonym for `FALSE`

Comment: You could also link to [this blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tip-avoid-using-t-and-f-as-synonyms-for-true-and-false/) for an example of why it is best to avoid using `T` and `F` as synonyms for TRUE/FALSE (and by extension avoid using T as a variable name as well ...)

Comment: people are fast here, I fixed it a min after I posted, then I saw the comment, I didn't pay attention to question enough

Answer (score 2):

You've been told not to use `T` as a variable name but you've not yet been given an answer to your question. It's not really an issue of R syntax, but rather a "feature" of whatever IDE you are using. Most IDEs are syntax aware and will therefore highlight in blue items that are meaningful inside the R language. If you run R from a Terminal session you would not see the highlighting.

If you need that feature you can get a package: `highlighting`

> Description: Syntax highlighter for R code based on the results
> of the R parser. Rendering in HTML and latex markup. Custom Sweave
> driver performing syntax highlighting of R code chunks.

Comment: good information (although "The reason T is highlighted is that it is used as an abbreviation for TRUE" is, technically, an answer to the question ...)

Comment: the `highlighting` package will give you syntax highlighting **in Sweave/LaTeX output**, not in the terminal.  Apparently `colorout` would work ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355369/r-syntax-highlighting-in-terminal